# JForex code editor color change

Tags: java, editor

How can I change colors in Dukascopy JForex java code editor?
JForex editor background is white and the tex color is black.
I prefer to use inverse color in code editors. I want a black background and white text color. How can I change this setup?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment. Please note that Dukascopy platform provides a very basic IDE and one should not expect the features known from other IDEs (Eclipse, IntelliJ etc.).